# Delete multiple rows from a table in sql server with a single call from client application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

Here is my requirement:

- I want to delete multiple rows of a table
- I have the list of all ids that needs to be deleted in the client app.
- All I want is to make just a **single call from my C# client app to delete all these records.**

What I had earlier:

`foreach (var id in idList)`
`{`
 `//Call a Stored Procedure which takes the id`
   `//as parameter and deletes the record`
`}`

This is a problem because there is a database hit for each item in loop.

Then I started using the **SQL Server 2008 newly introduced Table Types and Table Valued Parameters** for stored procedures for this.

- First have a Table Type created in the database which has a single column (of type of Id)
- Create a new Stored Procedure which accepts this new table type (Table Valued Parameter)
- In the Client code, create a list/Datatable with all the ids to be deleted.
- Make a single call to the database to make use of the new stored Procedure.

It is pretty straight forward in the client code, which goes something like this:

`SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();`
`parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;`

OK - Though I achieved what I set for, this definitely does not work for SQL server versions before 2008.

So what I did was to introduce a fall back mechanism:

- I introduced a Stored Procedure that takes **comma separated id values**
- My client code will create such comma separated ids, and then simply pass it to the new stored proc.
- The Stored Proc will then split all those ids, and then call delete one by one.
- So in a way, I have achieved what I had set for even on SQL Server version prior to 2008: **delete multiple rows with a single database hit.**

But I am not that convinced with the last approach I took - A quick search on the internet did not reveal anything much.

So can somebody tell me if I am doing the right thing with comma separated ids and all.
What is the usual best practice to delete multiple records from the client app with a single database hit, provided the ids are known.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your delete statement look like?

Comment: delete from tableName where id=@rowId.  The @rowId is an integer created after CAST ing the individual string after splitting comma separated values

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a stored procedure?  In other words what is wrong with building a regular DELETE * FROM Table WHERE id IN (1,2,3,5,20,25,50) SQL statement and just executing it directly?

Comment: but if you want to use WHERE id IN you will have to pass integer values no need of casting values to string @Abey

Comment: @Dan-Metheus,NetStarter - YES the WHERE ID IN() clause looks simple, but then imagine all that sql string concatenation that I will have to do in my client code. I don't see that as a very neat way of doing it - error prone and maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Abey I'm not sure I see your objection as either error prone or a maintenance nightmare.  It's kind of like saying look at this "for i = 1 to 10000/str = str + i + ","/next i" man what a maintenance nightmare it's doing 10,000 concatenations!  Even if you store the values in a temp table you can build the IN clause from that temp table as shown.

Answer (score 2):

hi you just concatenate the all values in the list  with delemeter as follows 1,2,3,4,5

here is the sample store procdure  for deleteing multiple rows

```
create PROCEDURE deleteusers  --deleteusers '1,2,3,4'
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UsersIds varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
declare @abc varchar(max)
set @abc='delete from users where userid in('+@UsersIds+')'
exec(@abc)
END
GO
```

It will delete the users with userid 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 2):

```
You can send a string containing comma separated or some other character(to be used for split) to send ids from C# end.

Create Procedure deleteusers
(
@ids nvarchar(MAX)
)
as
begin
DECLARE  @pos bigint,@count int,@id varchar(max),@I int,@Spos int
set @Spos=1
set @I=1
set @count=  len(@ids)-len(REPLACE(@ids,',','')) 
while(@I<=@count)
    begin
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ids, 1)


        set @id = substring(@ids,@Spos,@pos-1)
delete from  TableName where id=@id 
set @ids= stuff(@ids, @Spos, @pos,'')

        set @I=@I+1
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column delimited list of values, say @list, you can do what you want with this `delete` statement:

```
delete from t
where ','+@list+',' like '%,'+cast(t.id as varchar(255))+',%'
```

This is emulating the `in` expression with string operations.

The downside is that this requires a full-table scan.  It will not use an index on id.

Comment: Methinks you dropped a `%` wildcard at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon-Linoff. I think I can avoid some loops. But then it is just variation of what I did (Not taking away anything from the solution you have provided), but I was wondering if there are any dramatically different solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamic SQL option listed here is probably your best bet but just to give you one more option.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteusers  --deleteusers '1,2,3,4'
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@UsersIds varchar(max)

CREATE TABLE #DeleteUsers (UserId Int)

-- Split @UserIds and populate into the #DeleteUsers temp table

DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM #DeleteUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build SQL strings in code, I'd suggest looking at an ORM (object-relational-mapper), such as the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Comment: if you look at the problem statement and the description of the solutions I have applied, I haven't actually built any SQL strings in code. And I think that EF does not really support the IN() clause properly. I guess we can use variation of .Any() or .Contains() for SELECT statements, but what is the way for DELETE statement - any pointers on that would help.